# C++ multiple inheritance accessmodifier

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class A{...}
class B{...}
class C : public A, B {...}
```

Are A and B now both public inherited? Or do I have to write an explicit access modifier to every class?

Comment: You have to type it explicitly for every class, so: `class C : public A, public B`. (Its private by default)

Comment: I googled a lot but I can't find any information what the standard says. Can you help me there?

Comment: I guess you're looking for this: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access.base#2

Comment: @MichaelKenzel - Why post answers in comments?

Comment: @StoryTeller If am i correct, it doesnt exactly answer the *multiple* inheritance and so what OP is asking. It just describes the single inheritance modifiers.

Comment: @FilipKočica - If it's a wrong answer to the question, posting it in comments circumvents the quality control of SO. So it's doubly wrong. It's not a defense. Now, it just happens that it does answer the question. *"In the absence of an access-specifier for **a base class**"* . It doesn't limit it to a single base class, quite the contrary, it could apply to any of several. That's why it doesn't say **the base class**.

Comment: @StoryTeller I thought it would be a rather short remark to dedicate a whole separate answer to. But you're right, I hadn't thought about the quality control aspect. Made it into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for the base class list is basically (full grammatical specification in [[class.derived] §1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.derived#1)):

```
[private|protected|public] [virtual] <base-class-name>, ...
```

So the access specifier is part of *each* base specifier.

```
class C : public A, B {...}
```

Here, only `A` has an explicit access specifier `public`, the other base `B` has not explicit access specifier given, which means the default will be used. Since `B` is declared with the *class-key* `class`, its default base access specifier will be `private` (see [[class.access.base] §2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access.base#2)).